Error when building and deploying Flutter web app via GitHub Actions
When trying to build and deploy Flutter web apps via GitHub Actions, the following error occurs:
error: pathspec 'build/web/*' did not match any file(s) known to git

Here is the YML code from .github/workflows:
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.24.3'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Build Flutter web
        run: |
          echo "SUPABASE_URL=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_URL }}" >> .env
          echo "SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ANON_KEY }}" >> .env
          flutter build web

      - name: Deploy to production branch
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "my email"
          git config --local user.name "my name"
          
          if [ -d "build/web" ]; then
            echo "Build directory exists, proceeding with deployment."
          else
            echo "Build directory does not exist. Build might have failed."
            exit 1
          fi

          echo "Listing contents of build/web:"
          ls -la build/web
          
          git checkout -B production
      
          git rm -rf *
          
          git checkout main "build/web/*"

          echo "Listing contents of production branch after copying:"
          ls -la

          git add .
          git commit -m "Deploy to production"
          git push origin production
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  deploy-to-server:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build-and-deploy
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - run: set -eu
      - run: mkdir "$HOME/.ssh"
      - run: echo "${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}" > "$HOME/.ssh/key"
      - run: chmod 600 "$HOME/.ssh/key"

      - run: |
          rsync -e "ssh -p 20022 -i $HOME/.ssh/key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
          --archive --compress --delete \
          ./build/web/ HERE IS MY SITE


In this code, when I change the main branch, I try to build the Flutter project, move the built files from build/web/ to the production branch and push the files to the server from there. But an error occurs. Does anyone know how to solve it?

The first thing that is important to mention is that the build folder in flutter is ignored by git by default. If you look inside the .gitignore, you will see /build/. This means anything in here will not be tracked by git. If you are trying to commit this directory, that would be the first thing you need to address.
Then, it looks like you are mixing intents in your action. These three lines look to be part of the issue.
    git checkout -B production
    git rm -rf *
    git checkout main "build/web/*"


Specifically the line of git rm -rf *. If you have built the code on main, why are you checking out then resetting everything then checking out another branch?
Ideally in a release process you identify a branch where your code is sent to for building and deployment. In this case it could be the production branch.
If you want to build code on the Production branch, you should commit your changes to that branch which will then run your deploy action there. This way you know that:

Every time code is pushed to production
It is built and committed
The built binary/folder is not lost by switching branches

This ensures repeatability in your action. Please discuss further in a comment if this is on track with your goal or if I am wildly missing the goal here.
